# Pairing for Garlic butter shrimp and tortellini

Tags: pairing, food

I was wondering if anyone had some advice on a beer to drink with a super-savory shrimp and tortellini dish?

Dish details:
The shrimp are cooked in garlic butter, then the pan juices are rendered with either white wine or some of the boil water.  This is all tossed with the tortellini and parmesan.

The dish is very cheesy, rich, and savory.  I'm not sure what to serve with it, but I was thinking maybe a Belgian Wit?  Any ideas?

Comment: Great question for a different brew related topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the Wit is strong enough in terms of citrus like esters then maybe it would be a good pairing.

I think that many people like the idea of IPA with garlic and butter.  But I don't find it a good fit if the hops are too earthy and herbal.  You need that citrus punch to help cut through the fat of the butter and cheese. I find that American Amber ale pairs nicely with garlicy foods because the Amber beer tends to have more malt backbone than IPA does.

Another suggestion would be a Berliner Wiesse.  The sour tart flavors will cut through everything and it should pair well with the white addition.  (Actually, I sub berliner weisse into rissotto when white wine is called for...phenomenal!)

The only problem with Berliner Wiesse is they are tough to find commercially.

Comment: I ended up going with an APA, thinking it would be a little more toned down than an IPA.  It was a little too herbal for me (forget what brewery it was from).  My guest however went with a Brooklyn Lager, which had a malty backbone and a mild hop bitterness.  He said he really enjoyed it (maybe he enjoyed chasing my cooking down with it!).  Unfortunately my wife doesn't drink, so we didn't get a third beer in on the meal (although she makes for a cheap date/designated driver, so I can't complain too much).

Answer (score 0):

Saison Dupont